# itextsharp place Pdfptable at desired position

Tags: itext

### Header Content and Pdftable is overlapping

How can I place **PdfPTable at any position in the pdf page using (x, y) positioning like (100, 200) or (15, 100)** at any place on the pdf page?

**Header Table using PdfEventHelper**

```
public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    AddHeader(writer, document);
}

public void AddHeader(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    // set no of rows
    PdfPTable headerTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    // set the width
    headerTable.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width;
    headerTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

    PdfPCell company = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("Name", fontArial)));
    company.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    company.BorderWidth = 0;
    headerTable.AddCell(company);

    PdfPCell report = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("PrintedDate", fontArial)));
    report.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    report.BorderWidth = 0;
    headerTable.AddCell(report);

    headerTable.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - 20;

    // write rows to the pdf output stream
    Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;
    headerTable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, (document.PageSize.Height - 10), writer.DirectContent);
}
```

**In My Main Class I am doing like this**

```
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(pdfFile, FileMode.Create));

pdfWriter.PageEvent = page;

document.Open()
```

**Next Here I am adding a pdftable**

```
PdfPTable HeaderTable = new PdfPTable(2);
HeaderTable.DefaultCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
HeaderTable.TotalWidth = pageSize.Width - 80;
HeaderTable.SetWidthPercentage(new float[] {45, 45}, pageSize);

PdfPCell HeaderLeftCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(8, HeaderLeft, HeaderFont));
HeaderLeftCell.Padding = 5;
HeaderLeftCell.PaddingBottom = 8;
HeaderLeftCell.BorderWidthRight = 0;
HeaderTable.AddCell(HeaderLeftCell);

PdfPCell HeaderRightCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(8, HeaderRight, HeaderFont));
HeaderRightCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
HeaderRightCell.Padding = 5;
HeaderRightCell.PaddingBottom = 8;
HeaderRightCell.BorderWidthLeft = 0;
HeaderTable.AddCell(HeaderRightCell);

HeaderTable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, pageSize.GetLeft(40), pageSize.GetTop(50), cb);
```

**The result is overlap of Header Content and pdftable**

Comment: You **are** placing the table at a *specific* location when you call the five parameter overload [PdfPTable.WriteSelectedRows()] ( http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#writeSelectedRows(int, int, float, float, com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte)) (adding long links in SO comment is really a PITA, SO is choking on the link, sorry). The header is probably overlapping your content because of the calculated top margin.

Comment: @kuujinbo add it as an answer then...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [itext docs](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/table.html#rotation)-

> To avoid having the cell border and the content overlap, if you are
>   having thick cell borders, call the setUserBorderPadding(true), like
>   this:

```
cell.setUserBorderPadding(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have calculated the y position for your header table in `onload()` like `document.PageSize.Height-10`.

please set some calculated value instead of `pageSize.GetTop(50)` in the second table also.

Comment: Actually using something like `pageSize.GetTop(50)` (which es equivalent to `pageSize.Top - 50`) *is more correct than* `pageSize.Height - 10` as the latter only works for documents with the coordinate system origin in the lower left corner which is merely often, not always, the case.